# Force a Page Boundary Segfault?

Tags: c++, linux

I want to write a test (gcc 4.7) in which I allocate a page of memory, which is somehow next to a page of memory my process does not own, such that a misaligned read through the end of the page should segfault.

Is this possible and how can I do it?

Comment: Which operating system ? Linux ?

Comment: Yep - operating system is Linux.

Comment: Would two pages beside each other where you don't have permission to read/write/execute one page, but it is still owned by the current process be acceptable?

Comment: Possibly? I'm looking for anything to cause a fault if I read past my allowed buffer

Comment: There's a library that provides a replacement malloc that does this automatically: [Electric Fence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_Fence)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [mprotect](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mprotect) with protection = `PROT_NONE` to make a page inaccessible, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main(void)
{
    char * a = valloc(4096 * 2);            // page-aligned memory allocation (two pages)

    int status = mprotect(&a[4096], 4096, PROT_NONE);
    if (status != 0) { perror("mprotect"); exit(1); }
                                            // protect second page

    for (int i = 0; i <= 4096; i += 256)    // test - should fail when i == 4096
    {
        printf("a[%d] = %u\n", i, a[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compile and test:

```
$ gcc -Wall mprotect.c && ./a.out 
a[0] = 0
a[256] = 0
a[512] = 0
a[768] = 0
a[1024] = 0
a[1280] = 0
a[1536] = 0
a[1792] = 0
a[2048] = 0
a[2304] = 0
a[2560] = 0
a[2816] = 0
a[3072] = 0
a[3328] = 0
a[3584] = 0
a[3840] = 0
Bus error: 10
$
```

Note that a bus error was generated when we tried to read `a[4096]`.

If you run this under gdb you get a little more info:

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at address: 0x0000000100803000
0x0000000100000eff in main () at mprotect.c:14
14          printf("a[%d] = %u\n", i, a[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no simple way to make it a guarantee that the call will segfault.

From the language few, all access outside of allocated ( owned ) memory is `undefined behaviour`. And which result an access will have is even undefined but often? a segfault, but not always. So the solution provided by Paul can do the job sometimes, but not as a guarantee.

If you run your job under control of `valgrind` you can get always a segfault with accessing memory which you do not own. But this is not the default behavior. Also you can use a lot more libraries like `efence` or others to catch these errors. Also `memory-sanitize` from newer compiler versions is a start point.

As answer to your question: No, there is no way to a guarantee a segfault with simple c-statements.